# Google Developers Console : "The Project ID specified is not available. Please select another. These identifiers must be unique."

Tags: google-compute-engine

I deleted a project from Google Developers Console and tried to create another one with the same name/id which didn't work:

**"The Project ID specified is not available. Please select another. These identifiers must be unique."**

But now, No matter what name or ID I choose, I get the same error.

Any suggestions?

**Updated:** Logged in the next day and the Project ID was available without having to do anything

Comment: Choose a different project id?

Comment: Really the next day? Been 48 hours and I haven't gotten it back, opened a support case. Here is hoping... I do not know who would ever be okay with having a random number/name in the root of their project for the next 20 years, this is a deal breaker... They didn't even warn me that this would happen.

Answer (score 3):

Google Project IDs cannot contain the string "google". Type it in there and it's obviously a hard restriction, so it's pretty obnoxious that they don't bother mentioning it.

In my case, I was trying to set up an OAuth project, and tempted to name it `discourse-google-oauth-77235` but no matter what numbers I punched in, it would tell me it was unavailable but `discourse-goog-oauth-77235` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

1 - In your browser, press Control + Shift + N in order to open a new Incognito browser session. From here, please access your Developers Console, log into your account, and try again to create a new project.

2 - In case the previous step doesn't work, please try using a different browser, visit the Developers Console again, and try the same.

Regarding the Project ID (name), they have to be unique. Although you may not see a deleted project right away, the internal records remain for a length of time, hence the error you were seeing.